# How to paste images from Excel to PowerPoint VBA without using .Select method

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am writing a code that creates a PowerPoint from Excel VBA, using data from the Excel document. In this document, i have a Sheet called IMG where there is a series of images named "Picture X", X being the number of the current picture. The code I have for copying these pictures and pasting them on their respective PowerPoint Slide uses the .Select method, which, according to what I have read around here, makes the code run slower, and can/must be avoidable. I want to know if it is possible to avoid using the ".Select" method and still be able to paste the images from the excel sheet.

The code I am using is:

```
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Sheets("IMG").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
    Selection.Copy

pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Width = 121
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Height = 51
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Left = 580
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Top = 3
```

Thanks

Rest of my code:

```
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim excelTable As Excel.Range
Dim SlideTitle As String
Dim SlideText As String
Dim SlideObject As Object
Dim pptTextbox As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim SlideNumber As String
Dim myPic As Object



On Error Resume Next
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application


Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
pptPres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen
pptPres.ApplyTemplate "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\1033\Blank.potx"

pptPres.PageSetup.FirstSlideNumber = 0

''Consolidados
Set excelTable1 = Worksheets("TDCSD").Range("N280:U287")
Set excelTable2 = Worksheets("TDEXITO").Range("N48:U55")
Set excelTable3 = Worksheets("TDGPA").Range("N81:U88")
Set excelTable4 = Worksheets("TDSACI").Range("N234:U241")
Set excelTable5 = Worksheets("TDSMU").Range("N47:U54")
Set excelTable6 = Worksheets("TDRPLY").Range("N76:U83")
Set excelTable7 = Worksheets("TDInR").Range("N44:U51")
Set excelTable8 = Worksheets("TDPA").Range("N59:U66")
Set excelTable9 = Worksheets("TDIRSA").Range("N31:U38")
Set excelTable10 = Worksheets("TCOM").Range("Q8:AC17")
Set excelTable11 = Worksheets("TCOM").Range("Q24:AC33")


'SLIDES

'Slide 0

Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)

SlideTitle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPT").Range("F7").Value
pptSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle

pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Start:=36, Length:=65).Font.Size = 20
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.Width = 610

pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPT").Range("B7").Value

'Agregar el número de diapositiva en la esquina derecha:
Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 686, 510, 34, 29)

With pptTextbox.TextFrame
    .TextRange.InsertSlideNumber
    .TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    .TextRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(137, 137, 137)
    .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
End With



'Slide 1:

Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutCustom)
SlideTitle = "Introducción"
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 22


Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes(1)

pptTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPT").Range("B11").Value
pptTextbox.Top = 88
pptTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignJustify

'Agregar el número de diapositiva:
Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 686, 510, 34, 29)

With pptTextbox.TextFrame
    .TextRange.InsertSlideNumber
    .TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    .TextRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(137, 137, 137)
    .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
End With




'Slide 2:
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(3, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
SlideTitle = "Agenda"
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 22

Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 686, 510, 34, 29)

With pptTextbox.TextFrame
    .TextRange.InsertSlideNumber
    .TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    .TextRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(137, 137, 137)
    .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
End With


'Slide 3:
''Crear Slide y añadir título
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(4, ppLayoutCustom)
SlideTitle = "Noticias Relevantes"
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 22

''Insertar el texto desde Excel
Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes(1)

pptTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPT").Range("B24").Value
pptTextbox.Top = 68.8
pptTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignJustify

''Añadir número de Slide
Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 686, 510, 34, 29)

With pptTextbox.TextFrame
    .TextRange.InsertSlideNumber
    .TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    .TextRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(137, 137, 137)
    .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
End With

'Añadir imagenes
'Falabella
Sheets("IMG").Shapes("Picture 1").Copy
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Width = 121
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Height = 51
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Left = 579.4
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Top = 3.4


'Slide 4:
''Crear Slide y añadir el título
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(5, ppLayoutCustom)
SlideTitle = "Noticias Relevantes"
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 22

''Añadir texto
Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes(1)

pptTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPT").Range("B49").Value
pptTextbox.Top = 77
pptTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignJustify

''Añadir número de Slide
Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
    msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 686, 510, 34, 29)

With pptTextbox.TextFrame
    .TextRange.InsertSlideNumber
    .TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    .TextRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(137, 137, 137)
    .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
End With

''Añadir imagenes
'Grupo Éxito
Sheets("IMG").Shapes("Picture 2").Copy

pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Width = 108
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Height = 65
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Left = 592
pptSlide.Shapes(4).Top = 1.42
```

Answer (score 0):

Good call on avoiding "selecting" the object. The only time I really ever select is when I am intentionally directing the user to a tab/cell.

So how about this:

```
Dim s As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IMG")
Set s = ws.Shapes("Picture 1")

s.Copy
```

And of course you could loop through each shape on the worksheet:

```
for each s in ws.shapes
  debug.print s.name
  s.copy
  'Code for pasting the image
next s
```

Good luck! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to copy an Image from Excel worksheet (without `Select`ing it), and paste it to a PowerPoint Slide.

*Note*: I assume the part you set-up your PowerPoint presentation, and setting `pptSlide`  works for you, and the only thing left is **Copy >> Paste** the image.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPic_to_PPT()

Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myPic   As Object                                                     

Sheets("IMG").Shapes("Picture 1").Copy '<-- copy the "Picture 1" image from "IMG" worksheet

' set myPic to current pasted shape in PowerPoint
Set myPic = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture, msoFalse)

' modify current pic setting
With myPic
    .Width = 121
    .Height = 51
    .Left = 580
    .Top = 3
End With

End Sub
```

**Extra** (the safer mode): If you want to loop through all `Shapes` in "IMG" worksheet, check each shape's name if it's "Picture 1", and only then copy this Shape to PowerPoint Slide, then use also the piece of code below:

```
Dim CurShape As Object

' loop through all shapes in "IMG" worksheet
For Each CurShape In Sheets("IMG").Shapes
    If CurShape.Name Like "Picture 1" Then ' if current shape's name = "Picture 1", then copy
        CurShape.Copy
        Exit For
    End If
Next CurShape
```

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful. But the only thing is that the positioning doesnt work ith the "With " funtion. dont know why

Comment: you copied my entire code and the positioning doesn't work ? are you getting an error ? or it's not re-positioning ?

Comment: No, i copied your code for the images of my code (which is a long code and has other things that could affect this) . it didnt give me an error but when i opened the ppt the image was not positioned

Comment: @thePB  can u share the rest of your code ? I used this code and it worked. It puts the a small image at the top of the slide. You know it's 72 points to an inch?

Comment: @thePB I can't see in your edited code the part `Set myPic = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture, msoFalse)` , did you copy this line after you copy `Sheets("IMG").Shapes("Picture 1").Copy` ?

Comment: no, this is my actual working code, with your edit the positioning doesnt work.