# VBA: Exporting charts from Excel to PowerPoint, but my PowerPoint Application crashes without an error message

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

My goal: From Microsoft Excel, launch a PowerPoint Presentation ("PP") template. Once the PP file is visible, I am copying the first chart from Microsoft Excel, then adding the first chart to the first PowerPoint slide. The first chart and first slide are working as expected. However, I am taking the second chart from Microsoft Excel and am not able to paste it in the second PP slide because my whole PP application is crashing without an error message. After debugging, I have found that line 53 in the code is causing the error, but I am unsure as to why or how to resolve.

Beginning of the Screenshot:

[image]

Ending of the Screenshot and the Beginning of the VBA syntax:

```
Sub TJT()


Dim PPT_App As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPT_Pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPT_Slide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim PPT_Shape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim wk_Book As Workbook
Set wk_Book = ThisWorkbook
Dim slideCount As Integer
slideCount = 1

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''SLIDE 1 BEGINNING'''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

TemplateFile = "C:\Users\john-doe\Desktop\Default_Template_v0.potx"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set PPT_App = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PPT_Pres = PPT_App.Presentations.Open(TemplateFile, msoFalse, msoTrue)
Set PPT_Slide = PPT_Pres.Slides(slideCount)
PPT_App.Visible = True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

Set Chart1 = Worksheets("Inputs").ChartObjects("XY_Return_Vol")
Chart1.Copy
PPT_Slide.Shapes.Paste.Select
With PPT_App.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    .LockAspectRatio = False
    .Height = 5.2 * 72
    .Width = 5.5 * 72
    .Left = 1 * 72
    .Top = 1.72 * 72

End With
slideCount = slideCount + 1


Set PPT_Shape = Nothing
Set PPT_Slide = Nothing
wk_Book.Application.CutCopyMode = False
PPT_App.ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''SLIDE 2 BEGINNING'''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Set PPT_Slide = PPT_Pres.Slides(slideCount)
PPT_Pres.Slides(slideCount).Select
PPT_App.ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect
wk_Book.Application.CutCopyMode = True
Set Chart2 = Worksheets("Inputs").ChartObjects("Ann_Ret")
Chart2.Copy
PPT_Slide.Shapes.Paste.Select 'This is line in the code that causes the PowerPoint to crash
With PPT_App.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    .LockAspectRatio = False
    .Height = 5.2 * 72
    .Width = 11.33 * 72
    .Left = 1 * 72
    .Top = 1.72 * 72
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's rare that you actually _need_ to use the Selection object. Whenever possible convert it to a Range object.

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41995440/7599798